# Unknown attribute Foreground on element TextBlock WP 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, ivalueconverter

> Unknown attribute Foreground on
>   element TextBlock

I have this error, when I'm trying to
 change the Foreground color depending
 on "Read_State"

```
public class ReadConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool ReadState =(bool)parameter;
                if (ReadState == false)
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);// new SolidColorBrush((Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"]);
                else
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

In Xaml

```
<TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ReadConverter},ConverterParameter={Binding Read_State}}"  Text="{Binding Path=TexT}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, why are you passing Read_State to the ConverterParameter instead of binding to it and using value instead of parameter in the converter?

Comment: Read_State is bool, this value shows that message was read or not. I have a ListBox of messages and need to change color of them depending on Read_State

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error may just be a bit misleading.  You can't use Binding on the `ConverterParameter`.

You are miss using the converter, you don't need the ConverterParameter at all.  Your converter code ought to look like this:-

```
    public class ReadConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool ReadState =(bool)value;
                if (ReadState == false)
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);// new SolidColorBrush((Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"]);
                else
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

and your Xaml:-

```
 <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Read_State, Converter={StaticResource ReadConverter}}"  Text="{Binding Path=TexT}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

You might also want to have a read of this [blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/05/28/a-generic-boolean-value-converter.aspx) for future use.